# sed uses parameter from a string contained space

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm writing my function to replace an effective option in a file to my setting.
The 1.txt is like:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes
```

My function will process the file then output like:

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitRootLogin yes
PermitRootLogin no
```

The sed parameter is from a string generated by the function,sed_chain(), like below:
The problem is if there's space between ${pattern} and ${option}, then I got error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 46: unterminated `s' command

If there's no space between them, the function works, but it's not what I want.

```
#!/bin/bash
A="PasswordAuthentication no"
B="PermitRootLogin no"
F="/tmp/1.txt"


sed_chain() {
    args=("$@")
    file=${@:(-1)}
    pattern_params=""

    for i in $(seq 0 $(($#-2)))
    do
        pattern=$(echo ${args[$i]}|cut -d" " -f1)
        option=$(echo ${args[$i]}|cut -d" " -f2)
        echo $pattern
        echo $option

        pattern_params="-e s/^[^#]*${pattern}.*$/#&\n${pattern} ${option}/g $pattern_params"    # failed
        #pattern_params='-e s/^[^#]*'${pattern}'.*$/#&'"\n${pattern}${option}"'/g '${pattern_params}  # passed
        echo "*** $pattern_params ***"
    done

    sed $pattern_params $file
}


sed_chain "$A" "$B" "$F"
```

Comment: What does `$pattern_params` echo?

Comment: it's just for debugging the content of $pattern_params

Comment: Yes, what are you getting there?

Comment: *** -e s/^[^#]*PermitRootLogin.*$/#&\nPermitRootLogin no/g -e s/^[^#]*PasswordAuthentication.*$/#&\nPasswordAuthentication no/g  ***

Comment: Sorry bud, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping single-quotes around the expression.

```
pattern_params="-e 's/^[^#]*${pattern}.*$/#&\n${pattern} ${option}/g' $pattern_params"
```

Comment: It produces another error:
    sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

Comment: Sorry the stackoverflow commenting system is eating your comment

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround, instead of combining all of the parameter into one, I run sed command one by one for each parameter. It works fine. However I still want to know how to combine the parameters into one.

```
sed_chain() {
    args=("$@")
    file=${@:(-1)}

    for i in $(seq 0 $(($#-2)))
    do
        pattern=$(echo ${args[$i]}|cut -d" " -f1)
        option=$(echo ${args[$i]}|cut -d" " -f2)
        echo $pattern
        echo $option

        pattern_param="s/^[^#]*${pattern}.*$/#&\n${pattern} ${option}/g"

        sed -i -e "$pattern_param" $file
    done


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this
  [[:space:]]
perhaps work?